# send message from server to client (java < - > java)

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I'm trying to make a chat-like app. What is the best practice in sending updates to client? I was thinking about auto-requests from client to server every 3-5 seconds because of GAE that allows only http-requests. Is there better way?

Comment: GAE also supports XMPP (the protocol used by Google Talk and Jabber). https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/using_xmpp

Comment: And then there is the Channels API which looks useful for chats as well (but probably only for Javascript clients): https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/

Comment: In case you don't want to use GAE, google: `push notifications android`

Comment: xmpp is probably the one I was looking for, I'll try it, thank you